# populate variable with javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to create a variable that includes some literal text and a value from an input. The input is being properly set via Ajax. Here is my function:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#boat_id').blur(function(){
                var regQuery = 'regNum='+$('#boat_id').val(),
                classQuery ='class='+<?php echo $class ?>,
                allQuery = classQuery+'&'+regQuery;
            console.log('query= %s', allQuery);
            $.getJSON('../ajax/registerBoatAjax.php',allQuery, function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $.each(data, function(theId, theVal){
                    var $el = $('#'+theId);
                     $el.val(theVal);
                        console.log(document.getElementById(theId));                
                });
            });

            $('#ownerAMYA').on('change', function(){
                    console.log("num="+$('$ownerAMYA').val());
                    var disp_amya =$('$ownerAMYA').val(),
                         disp_name =$('$ownerName').val(),
                         msg1 = 'Registered to <b>'+disp_name+'</b>, AMYA# <b>'+disp_amya+'</b>';
                    console.log(disp_name);
                    $('#content-msg1').html(msg1);
                    $('#content-msg1').css('visibility', 'visible');
            });
        });//end boat_id blur
    });//end ready
```

The first console.log correctly shows the query to the ajax file. 
The second (console.log(data) correctly shows the JSON data returned. 
The console.log in the .each loop shows most of the values, but one of the values (#ownerAMYA) is missing. That value correctly displays on the page.
The console.log()in the on('change' function does not appear in the console.
msg1 does not appear in the console or the output.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: Presumably, `console.log(document.getElementById(theId))` doesn't show anything because the `theId` doesn't match any element currently in the document

Comment: That particular id is being populated correctly. The value shows correctly in the HTML output (that one input is on the page, and is the only one of all the inputs being populated by the JSON which is not hidden.